# How do I make a line of code run after specifically closing a top level window in tkinter

Tags: python, function, tkinter, window, toplevel

I have this bit of code

```
def choosesize():
    global textsize

    window2 = Toplevel()

    label = Label(window2,
                  text='Type the size you want for the text')
    label.pack()

    chooses = Text(window2,
                   height=1,
                   width=10)
    chooses.insert(INSERT, str(textsize))
    chooses.pack()

    butt = Button(window2,
                  text='Confirm',
                  command=lambda: chooses.get(1.0, 'end-1c') == textsize)
    butt.pack()

    window2.mainloop()
    print(str(textsize))
    note.configure(font=(font, textsize))
```

I want the stuff after `window2.mainloop()` to happen after I close the top level window that opens with this function, but for some reason those lines of code only run when I close the bottom window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change `window2.mainloop()` to `window2.wait_window()`.

Note that it is not recommended to call `.mainloop()` more than once.

Comment: I always forget about `wait_window()`!

Answer (score 1):

You don't want or need another call to `mainloop()` here. If all you want is for some code to run after `window2` is closed, you can use a protocol handler bound to a function that calls that chunk of code.

```
def on_window_close():
    print(str(textsize))
    note.configure(font=(font, textsize))
    window2.destroy()  # needed to actually close the window


window2.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', on_window_close)  # call handler on window close
```